# Who am I or How do I know which Element I'm dealing with?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Inside the following code how do I perform a test, and know which element was clicked?

```js
$("li,p").click(function(){
   
   // how do I perform a test, and know which Element it is?

   if( /* I'm a <li/> */ )
       // Do this for the <li/>

   if( /* I'm a <p/> */ )
       // Do this for the <p/>
})
```

Comment: Why use the same handler for li and p if you need to do different things for each?

Comment: I have the same instruction (a lot actually) to perform on the two of them. but there is some differences on others

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to use the [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/#expr) method:

```
$("li,p").click(function(){

   // how do I do I perform a test, on wich Element it is ?

   if($(this).is('li'))
       // Do this for the <li/>

   if($(this).is('p'))
       // Do this for the <p/>
})
```

Comment: Oh gosh, you're faster than me.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `this.nodeName`.

You can also write

```
if (jQuery.nodeName(this, 'p'))
```

Answer (score 1):

***[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/CfY8Z/)***

```
$("li,p").click(function(){
    if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "p"){
       alert("PP!");
    }else if(this.tagName.toLowerCase() == "li"){
        alert("list!");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `is()` function

```
$("li,p").click(function(){         

    if( $(this).is('li') )        
        // Do this for the <li/>     
    if( $(this).is('p') )        
        // Do this for the <p/> 
});
```